# Enemies following in SpriteKit get closer overtime

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

This is code that I had to update from and outdated blog post

```
import SpriteKit

class CreateEnemies {

var enemySprites: [SKSpriteNode] = []
static var lowerRate = 120
static var upperRate = 250

func spawnEnemy(targetSprite: SKNode) -> SKSpriteNode {

    // create a new enemy sprite
    let newEnemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"sharkshark")
    enemySprites.append(newEnemy)
    newEnemy.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)

    let randomXStart = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2000 - (-2000)))) + CGFloat(-2000)
    let randomYStart = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2000 - (-2000)))) + CGFloat(-2000)
    let xInt = Int(randomXStart)
    let yInt = Int(randomYStart)
    newEnemy.position = CGPoint(x: xInt, y: yInt)

    // Define Constraints for orientation/targeting behavior
    let i = enemySprites.count-1
    let rangeForOrientation = SKRange(constantValue:CGFloat(M_2_PI*7))
    let orientConstraint = SKConstraint.orient(to: targetSprite, offset: rangeForOrientation)
    let rangeToSprite = SKRange(lowerLimit: CGFloat(CreateEnemies.lowerRate), upperLimit: CGFloat(CreateEnemies.upperRate))
    var distanceConstraint: SKConstraint

    // First enemy has to follow spriteToFollow, second enemy has to follow first enemy, ...
    if enemySprites.count-1 == 0 {
        distanceConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(rangeToSprite, to: targetSprite)
    } else {
        distanceConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(rangeToSprite, to: enemySprites[i-1])
    }
    newEnemy.constraints = [orientConstraint, distanceConstraint]

    return newEnemy

}
}
```

I was wondering how I would make the enemies get closer to the target gradually the longer they exist.

I tried changing the variables every 5 seconds using a

```
let wait5 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5)
    let getCloser = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait5, SKAction.run {self.changeRates()}]))
    self.run(getCloser)
```

and attaching it to run a function

```
func changeRates() {
    CreateEnemies.lowerRate -= 25
    CreateEnemies.upperRate -= 25
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the cause of your issue or not, but your code might have another bug. I see you're using the constant `M_2_PI`. You should be aware that this constant actually equals 2/π, not 2π as you might think. I'm not sure whether or not that was intended, but I just thought I'd let you know in case it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here:
1) your random is based on a square not a circle, so you are going to find your enemies spawning more on the corners than in the center of each side of your screen.  I would recommend making a random angle between 0 and 2 pi, a random radius of I am guessing between 0 and 2000, and then setting your position using `CGPoint(x:cos(angle) * radius, y:sin(angle) * radius)`

2) your lowerRate is going to hit negative in 25 seconds,  That may become a problem. I would use a percentage instead:

```
lowerRate = lowerRateStart * percentage
percentage *= 0.90
```

This will reduce your sprites 10 percent of their current location, so 90 81 73 64 58 52 47 42 38 34 31 28 25 22 20 18 16 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4..... then be between 4 and 0 for a while.  This basically assures that your number approaches zero, but will never become 0.

3) Your random start and your distance constraint are not correlating correctly, and this may cause problems. I would recommend setting the position somewhere inside of your distance constraint radius, so your rates should be:

```
let radius = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperRate - lowerRate)))
newEnemy.position = CGPoint(x:cos(angle) * radius + lowerRate + targetSprite.x, y:sin(angle) * radius + lowerRate + targetSprite.y)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help however. I'm not the one who originally wrote the code. I just know that it does partially what I want except for the enemy getting closer overtime. Im not sure how to implement your code to fix the original.